# How can we divide lines in emails

Tags: apex, email, html

I am going to send an email with with few records. I need to divide each record data for each record. I think some html tags can be help but i am not able use. Can any one help me?

Here is my email code:

```
public class genericSendanEmailClass {
public static void sendEmailToAuthor(Map<id,List<Question_Answer__c>> sendingMap){
    for(id aid : sendingMap.keySet()){
        // Step 1: Create a new Email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setSubject('Quesitons updated');
        string Subject =  '';
        system.debug('+++++++'+ sendingMap.keySet().size());
        for(Question_Answer__c bk : sendingMap.get(aid)){
            
         system.debug('====aid==='+ aid);
            
            Subject = Subject +'========'+  bk.Account__c;
             Subject = Subject + '========'+ bk.Question__c;
            Subject = Subject + '========'+ bk.Answer__c;
            
        }       
         list<id> LegalTeamId = New list<id>();
        List<String> mailAddresses = new List<String>();
         list<GroupMember>  LegalTeam  = [SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId = '00GU0000002TUao'];
        for(GroupMember u : LegalTeam){
          LegalTeamId.add(u.UserOrGroupId);
        }
        List<user> Lteam = [Select email FROM user WHERE id IN : LegalTeamId];
        for(user Lt : Lteam){
          mailAddresses.add(Lt.email);               
        }
         system.debug('======='+ mailAddresses);
        
        String body = 'Dear ' + Subject ;
        mail.setHtmlBody(body);
        mail.setToAddresses(mailAddresses);           
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] {mail});
    }   
}
    }
```

Here is my email:

[image]
I would like to devide at each ========== .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user `<br/>` tag to break these.

```
for(Question_Answer__c bk : sendingMap.get(aid)){

         system.debug('====aid==='+ aid);

            Subject = '<br/>'+Subject +'<br/>'+  bk.Account__c;
             Subject = Subject +'<br/>'+ bk.Question__c;
            Subject = Subject + '<br/>'+ bk.Answer__c;

        }
```

It will break the lines for you.

Comment: Hi @Tushar Sharma, i appriciate for your answer, but  How do we give three line of gap for every loop repeat. I mean after three lines there should be three lines empty space so that will be looks good

Comment: @chris add <br/> tag three times.